# Deletion of a PHP object; also unset() and __destruct

Tags: php, oop, destructor, magic-methods

Are these correct:

1. Any PHP object always gets deleted after it is run (like the code of it).
2. `unset($objectName)` just stimulates what would happen anyway. The deletion will be a little bit faster (from RAM memory) but in the end it is exactly the same thing.
3. `__destruct` is like an event that gets run prior to deleting an object, so we can have it or not. Any code can be run within that.

Does `unset()` has anything to do with `__destruct`? Like it would just go to that (as the only step) and then delete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Variables/objects/resources get automatically deleted/deallocated when the script they're in completes execution. It is not necessary (or recommended) to call `unset()` on everything.
2. If you want something to be deleted/deallocated before the end of the script, you can explicitly `unset()` it, and it will happen immediately rather than and the end of the script. This can free up memory, but is usually used simply to remove the possibility of the thing being referenced again.
3. Correct.

> Does unset() has anything to do with __destruct.

Yes. Just prior to an object getting destroyed (either by explicit `unset()` or by reaching the end of the script), the `__destruct()` method gets called if present.

Comment: Thanks. Why would we want to "remove the possibility of the thing being referrenced again"?

Comment: @AndyRogers You might do so in a loop, to avoid the next iteration accidentally having the previous iteration's value still around.

Comment: @AndyRogers It's also commonly used to remove items from arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the info. I am still learning this (like 14-15 months of edu done so far) so I will get better at figuring this out "on my own" (like learning C and reading the source code). When we use unset() is this something like it goes to __destruct as the only step and then deletes? I  was watching a video and it was saying that there could be an association like this. Like we do unset() then it goes to __destruct, runs whatever is there and deletes. So yes, or not really? Not a big  difference but I am trying not to skip things that I dont understand.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeKc5VGUkPM - He talks about triggering __destruct with unset(), that this is how we destroy an object. This video is what got me confused about all this.

Comment: Destructor __destruct()
Similarly, you can define a destructor called __destruct() for a class. Destructor shall not carry any parameter. It will be run before the instance is destructed (or deallocated). Destructors are not commonly-used.

From the outputs of the above examples, it can be seen that the destructor is called on all objects when end-of-file is reached, before the program exits. To explicitly trigger the destructor, you can invoke unset() on an object. For example,

$t1 = new MyTime;
unset($t1); // Invoke destructor

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/php5_OOP.html - The above is from this url. So yes, unset triggers the __destruct. So this is actually the __destruct that deletes an object. Probably not... So I still dont quite get what it means. Like if there is no __destruct (as it does not have to be there) the unset() will still delete it, right? So what is the difference here?

Comment: The object gets deleted in one of two ways: implicitly at the end of the script, or explicitly via a call to unset(). In either case, if __destruct() is defined for the class, that is called immediately prior to deletion. Whether or not __destruct() exists, the object is then deleted. The __destruct() is offered to the programmer as a means to hook into the deletion process. You almost never need it. It is most commonly used to clean up things that might have happened earlier in the script -- maybe like delete any temp files that were created, or write out some debugging data to a log file.