# Replacement or equivalent to __destruct() and unset() for PHP 7+

Tags: php

I'm going through the journey of bringing our dating web app up to date past PHP 7+

I have been updating the depreciated code and squishing errors as they've popped up, thanks to the help of this site, and has a question in regards to our depreciated `__destruct()`  functions.

I searched my error I was getting thrown, and found this link on github that solved my issue: https://github.com/sajari/simple-linkedin-php/issues/4

So supposedly the destruct functions break after PHP 7, and commenting them out DID fix my issue, but it left me worried.

> Edit: Destruct still works, its just how my dated code was trying to
> use it

I have one specific instances of the destruct being called in one of our class files that builds a  job request page based on what job a user queries from our database.

```
/** free up memory
    $tmp->__destruct();
    unset($tmp);
**/
```

From what I can tell, everything is working fine, but I wonder what the consequences of this are. Should I replace it with some newer memory cleanup method? This app is so dated, I wonder if this clean-up is even needed anymore, or intentionally put in to stop a memory leak. My boss doesn't seem to know either.

I'm new to PHP in a professional sense, and would like to make sure this update still allows the same level of speed and usability for our clients.

Another stackoverflow question asked here: [Deletion of a PHP object; also unset() and __destruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153701/deletion-of-a-php-object-also-unset-and-destruct)

A user answered by saying that the values are already cleared by the complete execution of a script, BUT could be explicitly cleared to stop any unintentional references.

This just lead to more questions. When that user means script, do they mean the specific function call?

To wrap this up, lets say that destruct and unset call was to stop a memory leak, what is an equivalent replacement for it?

Thanks!

> I want to personally mark this question answered for my own sake. It
> was extremely helpful!

Comment: `__destruct()` hasn't been removed or broken in PHP7, but the way they were using it in the GitHub issue you linked wasn't the proper way of using it. In my IDE, the error from their code is `Cannot reassign $this`, because `unset($this);` doesn't make any sense. However, there's no need to call `$tmp->__destruct()`, because `unset($tmp)` will run it automatically. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php for more information.

Comment: Hey, I just tested out that fix, and everything seems to be working fine now. I have no idea why that was written the way it was, as I'm not the original author. 
I would like to update my question, because I'm still wondering if the explicit unset call is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
$tmp->__destruct();
unset($tmp);
```

You should never be calling destructors directly like this. Calling `unset($tmp)` by itself will indirectly cause the destructor to fire when the object is removed. So, this code actually causes the destructor to be called twice, which is almost certainly not what you want.

> When that user means script, do they mean the specific function call?

No, they mean that one particular PHP execution, from the first line of the first file to the last line of the last file. At the end of execution, everything is automatically freed. In PHP, this execution run usually refers to one single short web request, so explicit calls to `unset()` for the sake of "freeing memory" are virtually never needed because an implicit `unset()` is going to happen as soon as the request is done. You'd only ever have to worry about doing this manually if, for example, the `$tmp` object uses a massive amount of memory at the start of a request, doesn't need it for the rest of the request, and runs for a long time. If you're just calling `unset()` at the end of the request, it's useless.

It's most likely safe to remove both these lines. The first is redundant and the second is almost never needed.

Note, it's much more likely to use `unset()` to remove a variable from scope than to free memory, so take care to scan if there's some code later on that needs `$tmp` to *not* exist.